# how to represent call to super class in a sequence diagram?

Tags: inheritance, uml, sequence-diagram

I have a complex hierarchy of objects that we can represent, for illustration purpose,
like that:

```
class Base {
 public handle() {
  //base handling code
  onHandlingDone()
 }

 public onHandlingDone() {
  //base onHandlingDone code 
 }
}
//--------------------------------------
class Regular extends Base {
 public handle() {
   super.handle();
   //regular handling code
 }

 public onHandlingDone() {
  //regular onHandlingDone code 
  super.onHandlingDone()
 }
//--------------------------------------
}
class Special extends Regular {
 public handle() {
   super.handle();
   //special handling code
 }
 public onHandlingDone() {
  //special onHandlingDone code 
  super.onHandlingDone()
 }
}
```

Note: this is not my Design, I'm doing maintenance on a huge project. There are a lots of 'Special' implementation. Refactoring is not an option.

There is a lot of interleaved code: method are calling super class methods that are also super class method, and some call are to other methods are done at each level.

Now I want to draw some sequence diagram to help me understand what is going on.

How should I represent these calls across the hierarchy ?
- Unrolling the hierarchy would add lots of noise in the diagram, but will be accurate.
- Masking the hierarchy will result in a simpler diagram, but it is confusing (where is that damn method again, where in the hierarchy am I when I send this message ?)

Is there any usual way to deal with this kind of complex class hierarchy in sequence digram ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this if you unroll the hierarchy and have swim lanes for the Super->Regular->Base. However one way to minimise the noise would be to make a *super* stereotype instead of using self calls.

Comment: That's just wrong. There is only _one_ instance for an object inheriting from another. That means you can not have different life lines. In any case that would not be swim lanes which are only graphical elements with no defined semantics.